# How to use: split 'hh:mm:ss' string to milliseconds float in every row of a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new to python and I struggle with ML-Problem where I want to convert a column of running paces `'hh:mm:ss'` format to milliseconds. The paces are Type: String and Milliseconds should be in Type: float afterwards.

I have figured out how to convert single values with the following function:

```
import datetime

def convertMinToMs(s):

    hr, min, sec = map(float, s.split(':'))
    milliseconds = ((min * 60)*1000) + (sec*1000)

    return milliseconds

millisec = convertMinToMs(dataset['Avg Pace'].iloc[0])
```

I have no idea how to do that for a series of data. I tried to pass in the series with removing the `.iloc[0]` but this results into following errror:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you could use apply https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest possible answer:

```
dataset['Avg Pace'].apply(convertMinToMs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert column to DataFrame with 3 columns, cast to floats and then multiple second and third column:

```
df = dataset['Avg Pace'].str.split(':', expand=True).astype(float)
print (df)
      0     1     2
0   0.0  15.0  12.0
1  10.0   1.0  30.0

millisec = ((df[1] * 60)*1000) + (df[2]*1000)
print (millisec)
      0     1     2
0   0.0  15.0  12.0
1  10.0   1.0  30.0
```

But if need also miliseconds with hours convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then to native format in nanoseconds and divide for `ms`:

```
millisec = pd.to_timedelta(dataset['Avg Pace']).values.astype(np.int64) / 10**6
print (millisec)
[  912000. 36090000.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function of pandas:

```
dataset['Avg Pace'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Avg Pace'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Then you can get whatever yu want from those datetime objects.

Hope it works